# Django cannot run manage.py commands

Tags: python, django, windows, python-2.7, django-1.5

I'm taking a python project that was originally developed on ubuntu and trying to get it to run on windows.

I have python35 & python27 both installed on my system however only python35 in my path environment because that's the only one I reference outside of a virtualenv.

I used the command `virtualenv -p python27 dlenv` to create a new environment directory and dragged the project inside.

I then opened the project in pycharm and directed the interpreter to the `virtualenv python.exe`

Now the `setup.py` file allowed me to install all the dependencies from pycharm.

`pip freeze` shows I have everything installed including django 1.5.1 (the version it was developed in).

If I activate the environment then cd to the `manage.py` file and try to run any command (e.g. `python manage.py validate`) I get **ImportError: cannot import name ForeignObjectRel**

Although `python --version` proves I'm accessing python 2.7.11 I tried running just `manage.py validate` and I get **ImportError: No module named django.core.management**

Anyone have any ideas what the problem could be? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show the complete traceback?  Also, its unclear, but did you import pip stuff while in virtual environment.  If you didn't they won't work in virtual environment

Comment: `(dlenv) C:\Users\Luke\Dropbox\dlenv\distance_learning\src\distance_learning_app>python manage.py validate`

Not quite sure what you mean by import pip stuff? I think I ran one pip command to get MySQL-python

Comment: You need to run pip to load django within the venv.  If you do pip freeze outside of the venv it will show system modules.  If you run it inside your venv it will show what that environment is aware of.

Comment: Oh yeah I'm definitely running pip within the venv. I can see that the modules installed inside and out are completely different